# Implementing VARIABLE Math formulas in python

Tags: python, math, formula, calculator

so I am trying to do my second KATA 3 on CodeWars but I've gave up. I really want to know how should I do such a project which goes something like this:

I need to write a function which takes 2 arguments: examples and formula, both are lists including math formulas as a string.

For example, my examples are: "a + a = b", "b - d = c", "a + b = d" and my formula is: "c + a + b". My task is to calculate the formula. The correct aswer is 2a.

I have never done such a project and have absolutely no idea how do I "implement" those formulas and make is somehow work, my idea in the future of the project is to use eval(), that's it. How shall I approach this challange?

Comment: Essentially, you have this dictionary: `{'b': 'a+a', 'c': 'b-d', 'd': 'a+b'}`. You can substitute the `b`, `c` and `d` into your formula `c+a+b` to get `(b-d)+a+(a+a)`. Then substitute again and again, until there's nothing left to substitute. Finally, simplify the resulting formula.

Comment: @ForceBru wow, makes so much sense! Will give it a go right now, thanks!

Comment: @ForceBru that's an answer, not a comment. Please post it as such, even if it seems "too short to be an answer".